# Angular 2 Cannot read property 'x' of null

Tags: javascript, angular

I am learning promises and I am trying to get a simple example to work but I get the error. The promises role is just to check whether a certain name has been entered and produce a boolean error on call back

> Cannot read property 'shouldBeUnique' of null

Here is my component

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {UsernameValidators} from './usernameValidators'

@Component({
    selector: 'signup-form',
    templateUrl: 'app/signup-form.component.html'
})
export class SignUpFormComponent {

    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = fb.group({
            username: ['', Validators.compose([
                Validators.required,
                UsernameValidators.cannotContainSpace
            ]), UsernameValidators.shouldBeUnique],
            password: ['', Validators.required]
        })
    }

    get username(): any {return this.form.get('username');}
    get password(): any {return this.form.get('password');}

}
```

Here is my component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="signup()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input 
                id="username"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                formControlName="username" placeholder="Username"
                >
        <div *ngIf="username.touched && username.errors">
            <div *ngIf="username.errors.shouldBeUnique" class="alert alert-danger">This username is already taken</div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Here is my validator class where the promise is being made

```
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

export class UsernameValidators {

    static shouldBeUnique(control: FormControl) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function(){
                if (control.value == "mosh")
                    resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true});
                else
                    resolve(null);
            }, 1000)
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you want to learn promises and not observables? Observables are the Angular2 way and you are kind of wasting time learning promises in ng2 in my opinion.

Comment: Going through an online course, I still think promises would be good to learn

Comment: Since observables and promises are different concepts, and I have never used a single promise in any ng2 app I have built, I would disagree. ng2 is built on observables, and I found it harder to think in observables because I knew promises. Don't get caught in the same trap! It's like jquery vs angular, once you start learning angular you can't think like jquery and have to 'forget' jquery to do the angular way, same with promises and observables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `safe navigation operator (?.)` to guard against null and undefined values in property paths.

```
<div *ngIf="username.touched && username.errors">
    <div *ngIf="username.errors?.shouldBeUnique" class="alert alert-danger">This username is already taken</div>
</div>
```

This should resolve the error you are currently running into. Read more in the Angular 2 docs here:

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator